# SQL Server & SSMS 2012 - Move a value from one column to a new one to ensure only one row

Tags: sql-server

This is a problem that has troubled several times in the past an I have always wondered if a solution is possible.

I have a query using several tables one of the values is mobile phone number. 
I have name, addresss etc.... I also have income information in the table which is used for a summary in Excel.

Where the problem occurs is when a contact has more than one mobile number, as you know this will create extra rows with the majority of the data being duplicate including the income.

Question: is it possible for the query to identify whether the contact has more than one number and if so create a new column with the 2nd mobile number.

Effectively returning the contacts information to one row and creating new columns.

My SQL is intermediate and I cannot think of a solution so thought I would ask.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the number of columns you want to create? If somebody has 5 contact numbers do you want 5 new columns, or just the two columns as set out above?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)?

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back to me. Five columns would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that it isn't the best possible solution, since we don't have information on how many records do you have in your dataset and I didn't have enough time, so just an idea how you can solve your original problem with two different numbers for one same customer.

```
declare @t table (id int
                ,firstName varchar(20)
                ,lastName varchar(20)
                ,phoneNumber varchar(20)
                ,income money)
insert into @t values
 (1,'John','Doe','1234567',50)
,(1,'John','Doe','6789856',50)
,(2,'Mike','Smith','5687456',150)
,(3,'Stela','Hodhson','3334445',500)
,(4,'Nick','Slotter','5556667',550)
,(4,'Nick','Slotter','8889991',550)
,(5,'Abraham','Lincoln','4578912',52)
,(6,'Ronald','Regan','6987456',587)
,(7,'Thomas','Jefferson','8745612',300);

with a as(
select id
,max(phoneNumber) maxPhone 
from @t group by id
),
b as(
select id
,min(phoneNumber) minPhone 
from @t group by id
)

SELECT distinct t.id
    ,t.firstName
    ,t.lastName
    ,t.income
    ,a.maxPhone as phoneNumber1
    ,case when b.minPhone = a.maxPhone then ''
    else b.minphone end as phoneNumber2
from @t t
inner join a a on a.id = t.id
inner join b b on b.id = t.id
```

Comment: Hi, that query works for two numbers so thanks for that but I usually have more numbers than 2 to deal with. Any ideas?